# How do I convert my string?

Tags: c#, decimal, string-conversion

I have a string that can be up to 9 characters long including an optional decimal point but all the others will be numbers. It could be `"123456789"` or `"12.345678"`, for example.

What variable type should I convert it to so that I can use it in calculations?

And how do I do that?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry, I just literally started C# yesterday... and it's only my second programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float.Parse("12.345678");
```

or

```
float.Parse("12.345678", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

For avoiding these kind of outputs:

1.524157875019e+16

8.10000007371e-9

For integers you can checkout this link also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should convert it to `float`, `double` or `decimal`, depending on how big the numbers become.

You can use `Parse()` or `TryParse()` to parse a string to an arithmetic type.

```
string numberString = "123456789";
double number;
if (!double.TryParse(numberString, out number))
{
    // There was an error parsing ...
    // Ex. report the error back or whatever ...
    // You can also set a default value for it ...
    // Ex. number = 0;
}
// Use number ...
```

Comment: Well the number could be anywhere between `"999999999"` and `"0.0000001"`

How do I chose between `Parse()` and `TryParse()` ?

Comment: Double can use up to 16 digits. This is the range "±5.0 × 10−324 to ±1.7 × 10308"

Comment: Ok, and why would a person use `TryParse()` over `Parse()`?

Comment: Because of safety. You can handle invalid parsing yourself by either giving an error message or set a default value. Parse() throws an exception on invalid parsing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a question of precision and a bit of memory consumption. 
if the floating point remainder is important to you use one of the following:

1. **float** - 4 bytes, 7 digits precision
2. **Double** - 8 bytes, 15-16 digits precision
3. **Decimal** - 16 bytes , 28-29 digits precision